# Help with Computing eigenvalues and orthonormal base

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we know that $A$ is a symmetric matrix $2\times2$, and we have one eigenvalue $l_1=-4$ and eigenvector for $l_1$ is $(-2,3)$. How to find $l_2$ eigenvalue and build orthonormal base from eigenvectors?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Let the matrix be

$$\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\b&c\end{matrix}\right).$$

If you express that $-4$ is an Eigenvalue
$$(a+4)(c+4)-b^2=0$$

and $(-2,3)$ an associated Eigenvector

$$\begin{cases}-2a+3b=8\\-2b+3c=-12,\end{cases}$$

you can solve the $3\times3$ system of equations. (For instance, express $a$ and $c$ in terms of $b$.)

Anyway, you will have a little surprise.

Comment: I tried this but I always get 0=0, a=(3b-8)/2 and c=(-12+2b)/3 and I put it in the (a+4)(c+4)-b^2=0 and I get 0=0

Comment: yves-daoust it is always the same, I can't get b

Comment: @tanja That's the surprise...

Comment: @ Yves Daous but what is my solution then?

Comment: @tanja: as the equations say, any $b$. The problem is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

You know the basis will be orthonormal, spanning 2 dimensions and you know one vector which participates in spanning it. This means you need 1 more dimension to span (why?). Since we are in 2D, it is very easy to find a vector $v$ so that scalar product with itself is 1 and scalar product with $(-2,3)$ is 0 ( this is our ON requriement, remember? ). You can start with finding scalar product = 0 and then just normalize the vector will fulfill the normality requirement.

Now when you have found the second vector spanning the ON basis, you can multiply $A$ with it and by the definition of eigenvalue and eigenvector you can do element wise division to find the second eigenvalue.